# Ckeditor content into a div in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ckeditor

How can I get the content of ckeditor into a div when form submit button is click.
Here are my codes

**ckeditor**

```
<form method="post" role="form">
   <textarea id="post" name="ckeditor" ></textarea>
    <script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor');  
   </script>
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span> &nbsp Upload</button>
 </form>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function() {
var text = CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.getData();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: "text=" + text,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
            $("#newpost").append(data);
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

**Div**

```
<div id="newpost"></div>
```

I have try that but it is not working. Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Check console. are you getting any errors? is the server returning any data? put a `debugger` in success method and check the value of `data` variables. Also, always use a `error` method while using a ajax call to know if any error occurred or not while making ajax call.

Comment: Also, notice that the `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are deprecated as of **jQuery 1.8**. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks and also added `$.toast()` to notify if success or fail, but sadly I'm not getting any of them. no success nor fail notification.

Comment: At what moment your code is failing ? Can you get text from CKEditor instance ? for data: you should use `"text=" + encodeURIComponent(text);`

Comment: can you append text not data ? `$("#newpost").append(text);`

Comment: @SergeiZ it is like am not even getting text from ckeditor. I can't also append text.

Comment: This is what am getting in console, "SyntaxError: expected property name, got '-'

Comment: Is there any plugin I should include other than jquery and ckeditor for this to work?